# BlackBerry - Perform some actions before email/sms is sent

Tags: email, blackberry, java-me, sms

I haven't been able to found this on Google, so I thought maybe somene here knew if this was possible and if so, how to implement it =) thanks in advance for any answers!

What I am aiming for is overwriting this method so I can perform some actions before the sms/mail gets sent, then just allow it to perform its normal actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (**link update**) [SendListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/sms/SendListener.html) to handle sms send event, example: [How To - Display a PopupScreen from a SendListener](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800698/How_To_-_Display_a_PopupScreen_from_a_SendListener.html?nodeid=1442931&vernum=0)